# Unable to start OpenSSH service in CentOS 7.1

Tags: ssh, centos7, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to install OpenSSh server on a fresh CentOS 7 machine , although the installation went fine but when I am trying to enable/Start, or to know the status of sshd.service using systemctl I am getting an error ,

`"Failed to issue method call : Unit sshd.service is masked"` .

Thank you.

I have taken every steps mentioned [in this guide](http://www.tecmint.com/manage-services-using-systemd-and-systemctl-in-linux/),and CentOS docs but I am still unable to unmask the service .

Answer (score 3):

You can mask and unmask service. Masking is like disabling a service. It not only makes sure that service is not started automatically anymore, but even ensures that a service cannot even be started manually anymore. Mask command symply makes symlink to `/dev/null` like this:

```
 $ ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service
 $ systemctl daemon-reload
```

Masking a service is a permanent change, much like disabling a service.

Enable service first:

```
systemctl unmask sshd.service
```

See more about systemd : [systemd for Administrators, Part V](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/three-levels-of-off) by Lennart Poettering

Answer (score -1):

I fix this problem after remove and install again openssh-server:

```
sudo yum remove openssh-server

sudo yum install openssh-server
```